# What is the correct formula to convert from cylindrical to spherical coordinates?

Tags: spherical-coordinates, cylindrical-coordinates

> To convert the polar angle θ from cylindrical to spherical coordinates the equation is:
>
> *Note: $r$ is the radial distance of the cylindrical representation*
>
> $$
> \theta = \arctan\left(\frac rz\right)
> $$
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system):

According to my own derivation the equation should be

$$\theta = \arccos\left(\frac z{\sqrt{r^2+z^2}}\right)$$

Can someone please help here? Which is correct?

Comment: Those are the same at least for positive $r$ (try it with some values)

Comment: Well yes but for either negative r or negative z Wikipedia's formula doesn't give correct values.

Comment: Please add your work for deriving the equation

Comment: The Wikipedia article has a section on [Unique cylindrical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system#Unique_cylindrical_coordinates) which addresses the complications of allowing $r$ to be zero or negative.  If you have a need to use such values, it would be important context to add to the *body* of your Question, not merely mentioned in a Comment below the Question.

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai I did it in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after looking deeper in the internet I found [this site](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Book%3A_Calculus_(OpenStax)/12%3A_Vectors_in_Space/12.7%3A_Cylindrical_and_Spherical_Coordinates#:%7E:text=To%20convert%20a%20point%20from,r2%2Bz2) which also uses the formula that I derived.

The thing is actually both are correct, but Wikipedia's is only defined for $0<θ< {pi\over 2}$ while the one I derived is defined for $0 < \theta < \pi$.

To see how I derived it it's actually pretty easy: radius r, coordinate z and $\sqrt[2]{r^2+z^2}$ form a right angle triangle where $\sqrt[2]{r^2+z^2}$ is the hypothenuse and coordinate z is adjacent of θ, which means that r is opposite of $\theta$.
To get $\theta$, one can now use cosine or tangent as all three sides of the triangle are known, but when z is negative using tangent will give an incorrect angle.